# WSL and devcert react page problem with local SSL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ssl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got a react service project that due to a specific setup it runs on port 443 on development mode. It uses a dev-proxy that connects the local instance to a staging istance. The usual way of connecting is using [devcert](https://github.com/davewasmer/devcert) to create self signed certificates against a manually entered CA in the system, then modifying the `hosts` file with an entry such like this:

```
127.0.0.1     app.mycompany.local
```

Normally this allows developers to connect to their local instance and resolve the microfrontends to the staging environment.

Me, being the stubborn person that I am, use Windows with WSL. It has worked absolutely perfectly for years until this situation.

When I run the project on WSL, the server spins up fine, but when I try to access the website at `https://app.mycompany.local/a-page` I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error on the browser. This is even more curious when I run a `curl --verbose https://app.mycompany.local/a-page` in the WSL console and I get a `< HTTP/1.1 200 OK` with the content of the page.

Anyone know how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by obtaining the IP address of the WSL2 system by running

```bash
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet {WSL2_IP_ADDRESS}  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.20.111.255
```

and entering `WSL2_IP_ADDRESS` in my hosts file instead of `127.0.0.1`.

The address can also be obtained from the host Windows system by running

```bash
> wsl hostname -I
```